# How does Hibernate Search handle annotations inherited from a superclass?

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm having trouble creating a proper index structure with these entities:

**Person**

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    @ContainedIn
    private Set<PersonRole> roles = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @Field 
    private String firstname;

    // other properties, getter + setter
}
```

**PersonRole**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class PersonRole implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "personrolegen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "personrolegen", sequenceName = "person_role_id_seq")
    protected Long id;

    @MapsId
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @IndexedEmbedded(depth = 4)
    protected Person person;
}
```

**Talent**

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Talent extends PersonRole implements Serializable {
    @Field
    private String email;
}
```

In this model, a `Person` may have one or more `PersonRole`s. Historically the index has been the other way around, ie starting from `Talent` and including `Person`. However, when I deployed and saved a few `Talent` instances, looking at the index there's no `person.firstname` (or any person property) in talent's index.

I also tried working the other way around, switching `@ContainedIn` and `@IndexedEmbedded`, thus including `Talent` in `Person`'s index, but that didn't work either - no `talent.email` in my person index.

I prefer the historical structure but if somebody can point out a way to make the other direction work more easily that's welcome as well.

Sanne [pointed out](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2435287#p2435287) that a similar problem might only be solveable via a custom FieldBridge but Hibernate's JIRA is down for me and I've no idea how I'd go about indexing the properties of `Talent` here (there're way more than the one shown here, including several `@IndexedEmbedded`). So if anybody could throw me a link explaining that, I'd be happy to accept this as well.

Comment: How are you saving/searching the `Talents`?  I tried your code out and saved a `Talent` with a `Person`, and was able to see the `person.firstName` persisted in the index via Luke (after using the Reconstruct & Edit button, since the field isn't saved), and I was able to find the `Talent` by searching for the `firstName`.

Comment: The saving is a simple JPA entityManager.persist() on the talent, the search is done with FullTextSession that gets passed a lucene query string parsed by a standard QueryParser (no fancy analyzers or anything). But I checked the index beforehand with Luke and it doesn't contain the person subtree. Alas, time to build a minimal example I guess. Thanks for verifying!

Comment: This is totally embarrassing: after re-importing the talents, building the index and restarting the application the search works. I could also verify that using Reconstruct & Edit the entries were indeed present in the index. You totally deserve rep for that tip :)

Comment: Glad I could be of some help!  Reconstruct & Edit has saved me a ton of time in debugging my index-related problems in the past, so I'm glad I can get the word out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the OP's original problem has been solved, the answer to the question is as follows:  Hibernate Search will treat inherited, `@Field`-annotated properties as properties/fields of that class, and will index them accordingly (even `@IndexedEmbedded` properties of a superclass will be indexed with no extra configuration/effort).